# Why is my georeferenced image not visible in ArcGIS?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.0

I georeferenced a tif in ArcGIS 10, copied the folder into another PC opened the PGDB with 10.2.2 version, everything is loaded but i can't see the image itself. However the zoom to layer takes me exactly where it has to be. I figured it should work if i just add again the georeferenced image, how can i do that in ArcGIS?

Comment: can you see the image as a layer in the table of contents?

Comment: did you copy *all* the files that went with it? Is it still a tiff (you say pGDB.. have you copied it into a geodatabase?) perhaps the pyramids are broken, does it appear when you zoom right in?.. redo the pyramids and you should be able to see it.

Comment: Is the data frame's coordinate system the same as the raster's? Does the raster have a defined coordinate system? (Georeferencing doesn't automatically define the coordinate system)

Comment: @mr.adam yes i can

Comment: @MichaelMiles-Stimson yes, everything is on this pc, by now multiple times. redone the pyramids, did not help.

Comment: @mkennedy yes, they have the same coordinate system

Comment: I guess i am just going to re-georef from the clean tiff

Comment: First export the image and see if it's there.. use Copy Raster or Raster to Other format from catalog right click. It is slightly possible that there's some sort of compression or tag that is causing problems. If it's a file system raster you can also try Gdal_Translate or Global Mapper to convert or view in QGIS. Try converting to something else (bitmap, img, bil, GRID). There is a problem with georeferencing tiff files with an existing georeference but I thought that was sorted ages ago. Did you rectify the raster? if not what georeference did you use?